# R: Update List Variable In Package

Tags: r, list, package, global-variables, environment

I have an R package that contains a list variable. Several functions in this package use this list variable.

I would like to change the value of this list variable from outside of the package. I am able to update a function outside of the package using

```
library(R.utils)
f <- function(x) x
reassignInPackage("f", pkgName="name", f);
```

However, when I try to override a list variable

```
 global <- list(a=5, b=3) 
 reassignInPackage("global", pkgName="name", global);
```

I get the error,

```
Error in unlockBindingT(name, env) : use of NULL environment is defunct
```

Is there anyway to override a list variable defined inside of a package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at function [utils::assignInNamespace](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/getFromNamespace).

Assume you have defined the following code in a package called myPackage:

```
tmpList <- list(a=5)
tmpGetList <- function(){ tmpList }
```

Then the following code demonstrates an unsuccessful and an successful change:

```
library(myPackage)
tmpList <- list(b=2) # only replaces outside the namespace verified by:
tmpGetList()    # still returns original list(a=5) 

utils::assignInNamespace("tmpList", list(b=3), ns="myPackage" )
tmpGetList()    # returns the new list(b=3)
```